# how to prevent moving for the next command if current command is not success

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a script for adding printer my command is in below

```
 @echo off
    echo.
    rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n\\10.50.100.104\printer1
echo Printer Installation Completed...
```

need to display a error if mapping is not success

```
echo Installation not success or interrupted
```

Please advice

Comment: Have you checked the variable `%errorlevel%`? Most command line tools will set it to a non zero value if they fail. Something like `if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" echo Installation failed`.

Comment: its returning with, error msd "Installation failed along with Printer Installation Completed..." is it possible to remove success msg when its error

Comment: The `if`command also supports an `else` statement. See [here](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-5-if-then-conditionals.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) on fail `||` or success `&&`

```
@echo off
echo.
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n\\10.50.100.104\printer1 && (
   echo Printer Installation Completed...
) || (
   echo Installation not successfull or interrupted
)
```